# Help me speed-up this code - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, performance, readlines

Guys i am writing this program that goes through list of tweets and returns words which was use the most.

I want to make it faster but I wonder if you can help point out some problems  or areas which i can improve the speed. 
thanks

### see code below

```
#import string
import re
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint


class Tweet:
    def __init__(self, timestamp, userId, message):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.userId = userId
        self.message = message

    def getDate(self):
        tokens = re.split(' ',  self.timestamp)
        return tokens[0]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[timestamp=%s userId=%s message=%s]" % (self.timestamp, self.userId, self.message)

outfile  = file 
def readOneTweet(file):

    """ Reads a single tweet from the file, and returns the string containing the tweet.
    This will often just be a single line from the file, but may be more if it ends with a slash.
    """
    lineBuffer = "" 
    while True:
        # TODO: read the line and strip it

        rawLine = file.readline().strip('\n')
        if (len(rawLine)== 0):
            break

        lineBuffer +=rawLine

        if (rawLine[(len(rawLine)-1)]!= "\\"):
            break
    return lineBuffer 



def readTweets():
    tweets = []
    inputfile = raw_input("Enter filename: ")

    # move the try / except around a single tweet.
    # so that we can keep going if we encounter a line with an error.
    try:
        f = open(inputfile , "r")

        while True:
            tweet = readOneTweet(f) # readOneTweet is method
            if not tweet:
                break
            try:
                lineStrip = tweet.rstrip()

                split_word = re.split('\t',  lineStrip.lower()) #('/([^a-z])([A-Z]) ([0-9])/n:.;\]+/', line.lower())

                tweetTime = split_word[1]
                userId = split_word[0]
                message = split_word[2]
                tweets.append(Tweet(tweetTime, userId, message))
                if len(tweets) % 10000 == 0:
                    print 'read', len(tweets), 'tweets'
            except IndexError, e:
                print "bad tweet", tweet
    except IOError: 
        print "file not found!"
    return tweets

######################DATA ##############
"""
- Need to separate tweets
- Obtain information about each tweet - UserID, Time, words
"""

def writeWordFile(word):
    toWrite = 'test.txt'
    fileHandle = open ( toWrite, 'w' )
    for i in word:
        fileHandle.write (i)

def dailyMessages(twt):
    dailyMsg =dict ()
    for i in twt:
        date =i.getDate()
        #print  i.message
        #dailyMsg[date] =messageList
        if dailyMsg.has_key(date):
            dailyMsg[date].append(twt)
        else:
            dailyMsg[date] =[twt]
    #for k, v in dailyMsg.items():
        #print k, v, '\n'
    return dailyMsg    

"""
Takes dailyTweets and perform  word coun. 
"""
def dailyWord(tweetsByDay):
    dailyTweetsWordCount = { }
    for date in tweetsByDay.keys():
        dayTweets =tweetsByDay[date]
        if len(dayTweets) != 0:
            count = wordCount(dayTweets)
            dailyTweetsWordCount[date] = count
    return dailyTweetsWordCount


def wordCount(tweets):
    """Takes a list of tweets and returns a dictionary of counts for words"""
    N = 100
    # we'll build a dictionary mapping each word to a SET of users who have used it
    wordTweeters = {}
    for tweet in tweets:
       # print tweet
        for i in tweet:
            for word in i.message.split():
                if not  wordTweeters.has_key(word):
                    wordTweeters[word] = set()
                wordTweeters[word].add(i.userId)

    # we'll build up a dictionary mapping each word to the number of users who have used it.
    p = dict ()
    #print wordTweeters
    for day in wordTweeters.keys():
        usersNo = len (wordTweeters[day])
        p[day] = usersNo
    #print wordTweeters

    return  p  #wordTweeters, p

def searchForMemes(tweetUserCounts):
    for  key in tweetsUserCounts.keys():
       # for pmeme in tweetUserCounts
       pass


    """Takes information returned by daily word"""


def isMeme(word, day1Count, day2Count, day3Count):

    #takes the daily count
    # check if it is a meme
    #First -  check count
        #check count in different days
        # determine the if it qualifies as a tweet
        # if not drop it  do not do below checks 
    #Second - time stamp
        #CHECK ITS TIME TRACK
        #How is the count of over time
        # rise and fall
        # 
    #Third - user id
        # check if is form different users
            #how many of those counts are from different users
       pass 

def dayUserCount(z,word, d1, d2, d3):
    """ assume dictionary will be input"""

    # check if the word exist in the dictionary

    if z.has_key(d1):
        date1 =z[d1]
        #print value.keys()
        if  date1.has_key(word):
            print date1
            c1 =date1[word]
        else:
            print "word not used in %s"%d1
            c1 =0
    else:
        print 'date does not exist'

    if z.has_key(d2):
        #print value.keys()
        date2 =z[d2]
        if  date2.has_key(word):
            print date2
            c2 =date2[word]
        else:
            print "word not used in %s"%d2
            c2 =0
    else:
        print 'date does not exist'

    if z.has_key(d3):
        date3 = z[d3]
        if date3.has_key(word):
            print date3
            c3 =date3[word]
        else:
            print "word not used in %s" %d3
            c3 =0
    else:
        print 'date does not exist'

    result = "Word: %s , %s count: %s, %s count: %s, %s count: %s"%(word,d1,c1,d2,c2, d3,c3)
    return result           



# supportive functions 
def hashtag(tw):
    hasht =[]
    for word in tw.split():
        if word.startswith('#'):
            hasht.append(word)
    return hasht


def httpTag(tw):
    http =[]
    for word in tw.split():
        if word.startswith('http'):
            http.append(word)
    return http

def reply(tw):
    reply =[]
    for word in tw.split():
        if word.startswith('@'):
            reply.append(word)
    return reply

def reTweet(tw):
    rt =[]
    for word in tw.split():
        if word.startswith('rt') or word.startswith('RT'):
            rt.append(word)
    return rt






"""
Old functions 
"""
def writeToFile(tweet):
    #filename = test.txt
    filek = open('test.txt', 'w')
    print "writing on the file: "
    filek.write(tweet)
   # print " _____--------______" + tweet
    filek.close()

# count word frequency.
def f2count():
    N = 100000000000
    words = {}
    words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower()
                 for line in open('c.txt')
                        for word in line.split())
    for word in words_gen:
        words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

    top_words = sorted(words.iteritems(),
                   key=lambda(word, count): (-count, word))[:N] 

    for word, frequency in top_words:
        print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)
```

Comment: What did the [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) say?

Comment: You just dumped 267 lines of code here. Which part has performance issues? Have you profiled it?

Comment: Rolled back to revision with code, since there are already answers posted that refer to it.

Comment: This question might be better asked on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

```
if (len(rawline) == 0):
```

could be written as

```
if rawline:
```

You should never use `len(rawline) - 1` as an index, just use `rawline[-1]`.

I don't know why you use `re.split()`, when you could just do `linestip.lower().split('\t')`.

Don't use `dailyMsg.has_key(date)`, use `date in dailyMsg`.

When you iterate over `tweetsByDay`, you should really be doing this:

```
for date, value in tweetsByDay.items():`
```

that way you don't have to manually bind a value to the key.

That's just a start. There are many more issues to be worked out. I think you really just need to work on mastering Python -- it's clear from reading your code that either Python is not your first language or you learned from a resource that didn't teach you how to write it well. For example, why do you put parentheses around conditionals? That's not necessary in Python (though it's an artifact from Algol-like languages such as C or Java). Why do you use `dict()` instead of `{}`? It's preferable to write an empty dict the second way. You may find [this tutorial on idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yes  I am a novice and I want to learn how to code and so that why i am seeking for help! I appreciate the comments and feedback

Comment: if get this error 
 if (rawLine[-1]!= "\\"):
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Samsoni it's probably because the string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`wordCount()` can be run in parallel. Since each tweet does not directly depend on another, there is no reason to iterate over the list serially. Break the list of tweets into smaller lists, and then have a thread work on each sub-list. Once they have all finished creating their sub-dictionaries, you can a little work to combine them all into one dictionary.

**EDIT:**
An example of how to parallize summing a list. You would change the body of the thread to do whatever your task is.

```
from threading import Thread

numbers = range(1000)

class Sum(Thread):
  def __init__(self, numList):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.numList = numList
    self.total = 0

  def run(self):
    for num in self.numList:
      self.total += num

numThreads = 7
threads = []
perThread = len(numbers)/numThreads
for i in xrange(numThreads):
  start = i*perThread
  t = Sum(numbers[start:len(numbers) if i == numThreads-1 else start+perThread])
  t.start()
  threads.append(t)

grandTotal = 0
for t in threads:
  t.join()
  grandTotal += t.total

print grandTotal
```

Comment: thanks, how do i do that? I am very new in python and this program worked will scanning file less than 300mb but if more the program takes years. regards

Answer (score 0):

This code is full of non optimized snippets.

For exemple, each call of a function takes time. Don't do some useless calls to function, and you will spare time.
Some calls can be replaced with comprehension list: hashtag,httpTag, ...etc

I could help to optimize, but:

1 - I have not enough time presently for a long work of this kind

2 - we can't optimize because the code isn't complete: where are the following functions called ? :

```
readTweets
writeWordFile
dailyMessages
dailyWord
wordCount
searchForMemes
isMeme
dayUserCount
hashtag
httpTag
reply
reTweet
writeToFile
f2count
```

3 -  I'm tired to answer to new registered folk that turn up at stackoverflow with heavy questions and who disappear after that, sometimes without letting any piece of news or comment. Excuse me if you intended to not do so

### EDIT

writeToFile

f2count

must evidently be pulled out of the list.

Comment: See the code. F2 count and writeToFile are not called anywhere, those are optional methods if i decide to use them. Thank you for the feedback. I am very new here and hope to learn more from feedback and comments

Comment: @Samsoni Runga OK for f2count and  writeToFile , that was stupid to put them in the list. But the other ones ? 
 _"See the code"_ To see what ?